# Summarize the data using two Python data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. I would like to do some analysis by using these two tables. I thought of using Joins but it didn't work. Hence reaching out for help. Let me elaborate the problem with the help of data. This data is not complete data, just for understanding purpose I have created these sample data. In reality, the data sizes are big.

I have two inputs tables.

**Table1:**

| Month | Area | State_Code | State_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 101 | TX01 | Total_Country |
| Feb | 101 | TX01 | Total_Country |
| Feb | 101 | TX04 | South |
| Jan | 102 | TX01 | Total_Country |
| Feb | 102 | TX01 | Total_Country |
| Feb | 102 | TX06 | North |
| Feb | 102 | TX12 | Mumbai |

The point to be noted here is Area "101" is mapped to State_Name "Total_Country" twice because we have two Month - Jan and Feb. But Area "101" is mapped to State_Name "South" only once because it is active only from Month "Feb".

**Table2:**

| Month | Area | Brand | Price | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 101 | Nestle | 14 | 300 |
| Jan | 101 | Unilever | 15 | 380 |
| Feb | 101 | Abc | 10 | 320 |
| Feb | 101 | Nestle | 14 | 420 |
| Feb | 101 | Unilever | 15 | 500 |
| Jan | 102 | Nestle | 15 | 310 |
| Jan | 102 | Unilever | 16 | 390 |
| Feb | 102 | Nestle | 15 | 430 |
| Feb | 102 | Unilever | 16 | 510 |

This is the brand level data for every month in an individual area.

**Output Table:**
The output must contain Sum of(Price) and Sum of(Sales) at Month * State_Code * State_Name * Brand.

| Month | State_Code | State_Name | Brand | Price | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | TX01 | Total_Country | Nestle | 29 | 610 |
| Jan | TX01 | Total_Country | Unilever | 31 | 770 |
| Feb | TX01 | Total_Country | Abc | 10 | 320 |
| Feb | TX01 | Total_Country | Nestle | 29 | 850 |
| Feb | TX01 | Total_Country | Unilever | 31 | 1010 |
| Feb | TX04 | South | Abc | 10 | 320 |
| Feb | TX04 | South | Nestle | 14 | 420 |
| Feb | TX04 | South | Unilever | 15 | 500 |
| Feb | TX06 | North | Nestle | 15 | 430 |
| Feb | TX06 | North | Unilever | 16 | 510 |
| Feb | TX12 | Mumbai | Nestle | 15 | 430 |
| Feb | TX12 | Mumbai | Unilever | 16 | 510 |

Thanks in advance for help..!

Comment: What code have you tried out?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question itself, I did apply cross join / vlookup(map function) but the result I am getting is not a desired result. Here, more than code, I think the logic is quite important which I am struggling to get it.

Comment: why would you need a cross join here? what's wrong with a two step merge then groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) then create the summary values via [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum):

```
new_df = (
    df1.merge(df2)
        .drop('Area', 1)
        .groupby(['Month', 'State_Code', 'State_Name', 'Brand'], 
                 as_index=False, sort=False)
        .sum()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   Month State_Code     State_Name     Brand  Price  Sales
0    Jan       TX01  Total_Country    Nestle     29    610
1    Jan       TX01  Total_Country  Unilever     31    770
2    Feb       TX01  Total_Country       Abc     10    320
3    Feb       TX01  Total_Country    Nestle     29    850
4    Feb       TX01  Total_Country  Unilever     31   1010
5    Feb       TX04          South       Abc     10    320
6    Feb       TX04          South    Nestle     14    420
7    Feb       TX04          South  Unilever     15    500
8    Feb       TX06          North    Nestle     15    430
9    Feb       TX06          North  Unilever     16    510
10   Feb       TX12         Mumbai    Nestle     15    430
11   Feb       TX12         Mumbai  Unilever     16    510
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `pd.merge()` with multiple columns, so that it is a dual-key merge/join.

edit: you will also need to `drop()` the 'area' column

```py
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Month','Area']).drop('Area',axis=1)
output = df3.groupby(['Month','State_Code','State_Name','Brand'],as_index=False,sort=False).sum()
```

```py
df3
    Month   Area    State_Code  State_Name  Brand   Price   Sales
0   Jan 101 TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  14  300
1   Jan 101 TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    15  380
2   Feb 101 TX01    Total_Country   Abc 10  320
3   Feb 101 TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  14  420
4   Feb 101 TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    15  500
5   Feb 101 TX04    South   Abc 10  320
6   Feb 101 TX04    South   Nestle  14  420
7   Feb 101 TX04    South   Unilever    15  500
8   Jan 102 TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  15  310
9   Jan 102 TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    16  390
10  Feb 102 TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  15  430
11  Feb 102 TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    16  510
12  Feb 102 TX06    North   Nestle  15  430
13  Feb 102 TX06    North   Unilever    16  510
14  Feb 102 TX12    Mumbai  Nestle  15  430
15  Feb 102 TX12    Mumbai  Unilever    16  510

output

Month   State_Code  State_Name  Brand   Area    Price   Sales
0   Jan TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  203 29  610
1   Jan TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    203 31  770
2   Feb TX01    Total_Country   Abc 101 10  320
3   Feb TX01    Total_Country   Nestle  203 29  850
4   Feb TX01    Total_Country   Unilever    203 31  1010
5   Feb TX04    South   Abc 101 10  320
6   Feb TX04    South   Nestle  101 14  420
7   Feb TX04    South   Unilever    101 15  500
8   Feb TX06    North   Nestle  102 15  430
9   Feb TX06    North   Unilever    102 16  510
10  Feb TX12    Mumbai  Nestle  102 15  430
11  Feb TX12    Mumbai  Unilever    102 16  510
```